# How to sort rows from an mysql table using order by and order by desc without making it over complicated

Tags: php, html, mysql, sorting

I found an easy solution to make it possible to sort by each column in my html-table.
Now I also want to make it possible to sort by each column but desc, but with my idea for a solution the code looks over complicated because of the two ifs inside the if.

I can't think of another solution which might look better and overall be easier.

This is my code right now:

```
<th><a href="mypage.php?sort=type">Type:</a></th>
<th><a href="mypage.php?sort=desc">Description:</a></th>
<th><a href="mypage.php?sort=recorded">Recorded Date:</a></th>
<th><a href="mypage.php?sort=added">Added Date:</a></th>
```

```
<?php

$sql = "SELECT * FROM MyTable";

if ($_GET['sort'] == 'type')
{
    $sql .= " ORDER BY type";
}
elseif ($_GET['sort'] == 'desc')
{
    $sql .= " ORDER BY Description";
}
elseif ($_GET['sort'] == 'recorded')
{
    $sql .= " ORDER BY DateRecorded";
}
elseif($_GET['sort'] == 'added')
{
    $sql .= " ORDER BY DateAdded";
}

$>
```

And my first Idea was something like:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM MyTable";

$checkSort = false;
if ($_GET['sort'] == 'type')
{
    if ($checkSort == false)
    {
        $sql .= " ORDER BY type";
        $checkSort = true; 
    }
    if ($checkSort == true)
    {
        $sql .= " ORDER BY type desc";
        $checkSort = false; 
    }
}
```

I think it does not look clean, because I would need to do this for every column and my table should become more columns in the future.

Comment: so u r looking to code optimization? right

Comment: @devpro well yeah, I am still a beginner and can't think of another better solution and I thought maybe somebody knows what I should do instead

Comment: @Xxy : another solution is to use [database](https://datatables.net/examples/styling/bootstrap)

Comment: @PraveenKumar I never used a database before, so I need to read into it first how to include and use it. But I also want to learn it for myself.

Comment: u also want to sort by DESC order?

Comment: @devpro yes, right

Answer (score 1):

You can try directly sending the value in your call.

```
<th><a href="mypage.php?sort=type&sortType=ASC/DESC">Type:</a></th>
<th><a href="mypage.php?sort=description&sortType=ASC/DESC">Description:</a></th>
<th><a href="mypage.php?sort=daterecorded&sortType=ASC/DESC">Recorded Date:</a></th>
<th><a href="mypage.php?sort=dateadded&sortType=ASC/DESC">Added Date:</a></th>

<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM MyTable ORDER BY ".$_GET['sort']." ".$_GET['sortType'];
?>
```

Obviously you will have to make sanity check as you are directly passing the call to DB.

Note - "&sortType=ASC/DESC", only one of ASC or DESC to be sent

Comment: what about DESC??

Comment: You want to make descending call?

Comment: as OP mentioned in question, order by and order by desc. here just order by means ASC i think

Comment: Edited the response for both

Comment: editing will generate syntax error, please run on your machine

Comment: I apologise. I mixed the syntax with language. This should work

Comment: As I said before you have to place sanity checks.

Comment: I am not at home and will try it out later, but I am a bit confused, for what is the first sort?

Comment: @sc0rp1on well the problem is that only one of asc or desc will work so and the goal is to make both work, also it won't select the default table because it is waiting on a order by = ""

Comment: I already assumed that you would have two buttons to sort desc and asc. Place separate call of variable on each

Answer (score 1):

I would use it : ([DOC](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php))

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM MyTable";

switch($_GET['sort']):
    case 'type':
        $sql .= " ORDER BY type";
        break;
    case 'desc':
        $sql .= " ORDER BY Description";
        break;
    case 'recorded':
        $sql .= " ORDER BY DateRecorded";
        break;
    case 'added':
        $sql .= " ORDER BY DateAdded";
        break;
endswitch;
```

And you can add as many 'case' as you want to !

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[datatable](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side)** for your problem solution. Please check below code

HTML file code

```
<!-- Need to add this CSS and JS in your HTML page -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
    //This code used to initialise the table shown
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#example').DataTable( {
            "processing": true,
            "serverSide": true,
            "ajax": "server_processing.php"
        } );
    } );
</script>

<table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Type:</th>
            <th>Description:</th>
            <th>Recorded Date:</th>
            <th>Added Date:</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

Or You can check this [blog](https://itsolutionstuff.com/post/php-jquery-datatables-with-mysql-database-example-from-scratchexample.html)